# Are APKs automatically updated by Playstore

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I have created an [Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.police.policecontact), published an initial version on Google Play Store and installed the APK on a test device.

How can i update new version without prompting?

> I have seen sometimes Play store send notification for update
>   available and user can update after click on that notification but
>   some application is updating automatically.

**hows it possible.?**

I want that user get update automatically.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: No dear, i don't know but i have created business app and that i want to upload on app store for specific users and want to update everytime when i change something in app.

Comment: If those are company devices and the company has administrative power over those devices, then the administrator could deploy those app updates Over-The-Air (but that's about it). The only next easier strategy would be to create an hybrid app that pulls most of its content from the web. Or to create an app that prevents itself from running if an update is available, to make sure all the users are using the same version.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I had updated my app on yesterday and currently that is updated in my device without prompting? how is it possible?

Comment: Two possible reasons (that I can think of). The app didn't finish updating yesterday, so it updated the next time you were within wifi range. Second reason, if you updated another app yesterday, and if Google Play opened up a dialog asking you if you wanted to turn on automatic updates, that means you unwittingly turned on automatic updating for all your apps (yes, that dialog is very misleading). That's why rooting one's phone and having a solution like Titanium Backup can be very useful. If you don't like a particular update, Titanium Backup allows you to roll back to the last version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible (unless the user clicked on the checkbox update automatically).

The only thing you could do is build yourself a shell of an application that would update itself from the internet when it gets run (but that would be quite an undertaking on your part and probably not worth your time).

Answer (score 1):

No. Google Play cannot update applications automatically without user permission.